# Two user-agents that should be fed the mobile version of chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

I had some time this weekend to play around with a couple of mobile operating systems on my Nexus 5. Both of them, unfortunately, received the desktop version of chat rather than the mobile one.

Those two operating systems are:

- **[FirefoxOS](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/os/)** - user-agent is:

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; rv:34.0) Gecko/34.0 Firefox/34.0
  ```
- **[SailfishOS](https://sailfishos.org/)** - user-agent is:

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Maemo; Linux; U; Jolla; Sailfish; Mobile; rv:29.0) Gecko/29.0 Firefox/29.0 SailfishBrowser/1.0
  ```

It would be terrific if these two browsers defaulted to the mobile version of chat.